# Testing a path always returns False

Tags: powershell, windows-10

OS: Windows 10, 
Powershell: 5.1

I have the following Powershell Code

```
Test-Path -Path "$drive`\"
```

where $drive is a drive letter, I'm checking to see if a drive letter is mapped to a folder (be it network or local) and im always getting a value of False

Comment: Did you include the : in the $drive assignment?

Comment: There's no colon `:` in the string for the path. Use "$drive`:\" instead.

Comment: `-Path "${drive}:\"` works also if the colon is not present in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot neglect the colon (`:`) in your path:

```
Test-Path -Path C:\
```

Additionally, the escape (`` ` ``) is entirely unnecessary here.

If you need to use a variable, you can use variable-delimiters (`${}`) in the string:

```
Test-Path -Path ${drive}:\
```

---

But if your goal is to check if a drive is mapped, you should use:

```
Get-PSDrive -Name <driveletter>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very new to Powershell, this helps a bunch =)